# Persistant connections doesn't work properly after migrating to Django 4.2

Tags: python, django, oracle

after migrating from django 3.2 to 4.2 I've noticed persistant connections doesn't work the same for the new version.
I'm using CONN_MAX_AGE=20 setting

For Django 3.2 I can see that oracle doesn't create new sessions in v$session table on each request.
But in Django 4.2 there is new session created for each request even though we haven't changed anything in the database connections.

**STACK:**

- python 3.9.16
- django 4.2.5
- oracle 19.16.0

Any ideas how to recreate the old behaviour on the new version of Django?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your issue is related to following problem in Django 4.0+:
https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/33497#comment:15

If you are using `asgi` to run Django app, there is an option to downgrade django back to 3.2, or wait until Django 5.1 that will add connection pool support.

Comment: Thanks, downgrade is not an option as django 3.2 is loosing support at the end of this month. 
And waiting for 5.1. is not an option neither as pool option will be added only to postgres: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/5.1/#database-backends